# Как преобразовать QLayoutItem в QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, типы-данных, преобразование

Имеется слой QGridLayot на нем расположены виджеты QLineEdit. Я пытаюсь вытащить эти QLineEdit и считать/изменить их текст. Но программа крашится.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            QLayoutItem *item = grid->itemAtPosition(m,n);
            QLineEdit *line = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(item);
            line->setText("1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Во-первых, сохрани указатели на них при создании и не страдай.. Во-вторых, `itemAtPosition(i,j)`, а не `m` и `n`; В-третьих, после `dynamic_cast`'а надо проверять не нулевой ли указатель. В-четвёртых для QObject'ов есть `qobject_cast`.

Comment: А куда мне указатели сохранить? В массив? Как вообще это сделать?

Comment: буду премного благодарен за пример

Comment: Сохрани в QList или хотя бы в массив... общий детальный пример с объяснениями потянет на пару глав из букваря по программированию/документации... а от состряпанного наспех без знания того, как ты создаёшь объекты почти наверняка пользы ни какой не будет....

Comment: Спасибо больше! Сделал через QList

Comment: Контейнеры сами память очищают?

Comment: Поздравляю, хорошим тоном будет написать ответ на свой вопрос... Про память, свою собственную — да, сами очищают. Сами виджеты удаляются при удалении родителя...